# Adding an additional resource on serverless for AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I have a serverless app with a http event. I need to create a child resource to the endpoint created by serverless.

How can I accomplish this with serverless?

The template looks like this so far:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  region: <REGION>
functions:
  myFunc:
    timeout: 30
    handler: "index.handler" 
    name: "myFunc"
  events:
  - http:
    path: /myFunc
    method: post
    cors: true

resources:
  Resources:
    saysResource:
      Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource"
      Properties:
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi 
        ParentId:
          Ref: <NEED_/myFunc_RESOURCE_ID_HERE>
        PathPart: "{says}"

  GetMethod:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
        Properties:
          HttpMethod: GET
          RequestParameters:
            'method.request.path.says': true
          RestApiId:
            Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
          ResourceId:
            Ref: saysResource
          Integration:
            Type: aws
            Credentials:
              Ref: S3ReadAccessRole
            IntegrationHttpMethod: GET
            PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_MATCH
            RequestParameters:
              'integration.request.path.key': 'method.request.path.says'
            Uri:  'arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/users/{key}'
```

As an attempt to get it working, I re-declaration of the resource for `/myFunc` was performed(hoping that CFN would not create already created resources):

```
myFuncResource:
  Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource"
  Properties:
    RestApiId:
      Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
    ParentId:
      Fn::GetAtt:
        - ApiGatewayRestApi
        - RootResourceId
    PathPart: "/myFunc"
```

This failed with the error:

```
An error occurred: myFuncResource - Another resource with the same parent 
already has this name: my-func (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 
409; Error Code: ConflictException; Request ID: <Request_Id>).
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: @HimanshuBansal I also tried re-declaring the resource in the template, that resulted in a stack_failed due to a duplicate declaration of `/myFunc`. After reverting that I am not sure how to proceed with the problem.

Comment: can you add the error stack?

Comment: @HimanshuBansal updated. Please have a look.

Comment: its a conflict of name... you can try to use a different name for the resource

Comment: @HimanshuBansal I would like to get the id of the resource created by serverless and create a child of the resource. That is an important requirement.

Comment: name: "myFunc"  <--- rename this

Comment: Let us know if it got resolved.. So others can get help from it as well..

Comment: @HimanshuBansal The question has not been resolved, the wish is to keep using the route created by serverless and not to rename the route or to re-declare the route.

Comment: there might me a resource or function with that time already present "myFunc". Can you try to run your code in some other account?

Comment: @HimanshuBansal The name `myFunc` is an example and a strawman. I do not wish to rename or find the function. I need access to the id of the resource created by serverless.

Comment: actually there is a resource with the name that you are trying to create the resource.. resources can not have same name.. as you can in the error stack that you provided.. `Another resource with the same parent 
already has this name: my-func`... just rename and try .. and see if it is giving any other error or not.. Its just a test... once it is successful .. we can be sure that the function is correct otherwise there is issue with the function and we can debug it.